# How to change a logo color on different sections of a website?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm making a website with a white logo on the navbar. The logo is only visible on the homepage because the rest of the website's sections (About, shop, contact) have a white background. I'd like to make it change with a script that triggers a class, but given my rookie skills, I'm all ears :).

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this ? Stack-over flow is not a free coding service you need to provide us your minimum efforts to achieve this or if you are stuck at something so some one can help with your code! Also consider doing your own [research](https://stackoverflow.com/search) or provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your work. Read here how to ask a [Good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: you certainly don't need a script or any advanced coding.  You are talking about separate web pages, so you can just create multiple logo image files and load the image you want for the page you want. Homepage: `<img src="whitelogo.png"/>`, About: `<img src="redlogo.png"/>` etc etc.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail @AlwaysHelping. And thank you, Chris, for the suggestion, it worked!